# Возможно ли получить код функции имея её название и старт адрес?

Tags: python

Возможно ли получить код функции имея её название и старт адрес?

Получил названия функций и адрес старта функции через PyInjector, возможно как то получить полную функцию в отедльный txt файл?

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону встроенного модуля `inspect`

Comment: Вы точно для Python пытаетесь это сделать? Можно поинтересоваться -  зачем?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет, такой возможности не существует. Для получения полного исходного кода функции вам придется использовать декомпилятор, такой как IDA Pro или OllyDbg.